# How efficiently use SDL_RenderFillRects?

Tags: sdl2

For the sake of learning C++, I would like to optimize a "Game of life" project I made. 
In my first attempt, I used a bunch of SDL_RenderFillRect to draw the board squares. 
In my second attempt, I used a single SDL_RenderFillRects to avoid the cost of calling the GPU a lot of times.

However, I am probably wrong in my second implementation because it is not faster than the first one (or barely 5%). Moreover, my implementation is all but elegant.

In the two cases, I only draw the living cells.

The SDL_RenderFillRect solution:

```
SDL_Rect fillRect;
for (int column=0; column<array_width; ++column)
{
    for (int row=0; row<array_height; ++row)
    {
        if (board[column][row]) // // Checks if the cell is alive
        {
            fillRect = {column*CELL_SPACE,row*CELL_SPACE,CELL_SIZE,CELL_SIZE};
            SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRect);
        }
    }
}
```

The SDL_RenderFillRects solution:

```
SDL_Rect fillRect;
static SDL_Rect rect_list[120000]; // The list of squares to be drawn
int array_index_count = 0;
for (int column=0; column<array_width; ++column)
{
    for (int row=0; row<array_height; ++row)
    {
        if (board[column][row]) // Checks if the cell is alive
        {
            fillRect = {column*CELL_SPACE,row*CELL_SPACE,CELL_SIZE,CELL_SIZE};
            rect_list[array_index_count] = fillRect; // Adds the cell to the array
            ++array_index_count;
        }
    }
}
SDL_RenderFillRects(gRenderer, rect_list, array_index_count);
```

I am not happy with the way I use SDL_RenderFillRects. 
First, I don't know in advance how many living cells there will be, forcing me to declare an oversized array. 
Second, I indeed avoided a lot of SDL_RenderFillRect calls, but at the price of long iteratings over the rect_list array.

How to use the SDL_RenderFillRects function properly?

Comment: Have you specifically identified a performance bottleneck with this part of the code? Also, what version of SDL are you on, one of the more recent releases added batching I think?

Comment: I installed SDL2 a week ago so I have the last version! I didn't identified performance bottlenecks, just measured their overall execution time. The only difference is that in the first version, I call SDL_RenderFillRect for each cell, and in the second version, I add each SDL_RenderFillRect to an array which I then pass to SDL_RenderFillRects. Maybe the added iteration time doesn't compensate for the GPU call gains, but it would negate the whole point of having a SDL_RenderFillRects function I suppose :/